# Azure GraphClient Get Users By Group Names

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to retrieve user list from AAD by a list of group names.

This code:

```
var roleGroups = new string[] { "Group Name 1", "Group Name 2" };

ActiveDirectoryClient client = AuthenticationHelper.GetActiveDirectoryClient();

var users = client.Users.Where(u => u.CheckMemberGroupsAsync(roleGroups).Result.Any());
```

throws:

> CheckMemberGroupsAsync declared on type
>   'Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.IDirectoryObject' cannot
>   be called with instance of type
>   'Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.Internal.User'

I've also tried:

```
  client.Users.Where(u =>((User)u).MemberOf.OfType<Group>()             
   .Any(g => roleGroups.Contains(g.DisplayName))).ExecuteAsync()         
    .Result.CurrentPage.Select(u => (User)u).ToList();
```

And

```
client.Users.Where(u => u.GetMemberGroupsAsync(null).Result.Any(g => roleGroups.Contains(g)));
```

which throws:

> GetMemberGroupsAsync declared on type
>   'Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.IDirectoryObject' cannot
>   be called with instance of type
>   'Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.Internal.User'

How can I get a list of users (`Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.User`) by a list of group names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do this.

```
 var groupUsers = new List<User>();

            foreach (var groupName in roleGroups)
            {
                var groups = client.Groups.Where(g => g.DisplayName == groupName).Expand(g => g.Members)
                    .ExecuteAsync()
                    .Result.CurrentPage.ToList();

                var users = groups.SelectMany(g => g.Members.CurrentPage.Select(m => m as User)).Where(u => u != null);

                if (users.Any())
                {
                    groupUsers.AddRange(users);
                }
            }
```

But I still believe there is a better solution.

Note that `Expand(g => g.Members)` will return max 20 objects. And also if you have a lot of users in your Azure AD you have to iterate through all pages, not only `g.Members.CurrentPage`